# Node.js multiple query transactions

Tags: javascript, node.js, transactions

I'm using the following function for handling multiple query transactions:

### db.js

```
function waterfall (tasks, callback) {
    pg.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        //client.query(begin_transaction, function (err) {
        client.query('BEGIN', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                done();
                return callback(err);
            }

            var wrapIterator = function (iterator) {
                return function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        //client.query(rollback_transaction, function () {
                        client.query('ROLLBACK', function () {
                            done();
                            callback(err);
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
                        var next = iterator.next();
                        if (next) {
                            args.unshift(client);
                            args.push(wrapIterator(next));
                        }
                        else {
                            args.unshift(client);
                            args.push(function (err, results) {
                                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
                                if (err) {
                                    //client.query(rollback_transaction, function () {
                                    client.query('ROLLBACK', function () {
                                        done();
                                        callback(err);
                                    });
                                }
                                else {
                                    //client.query(commit_transaction, function () {
                                    client.query('COMMIT', function () {
                                        done();
                                        callback.apply(null, args);
                                    })
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        async.setImmediate(function () {
                            iterator.apply(null, args);
                        });
                    }
                };
            };
            wrapIterator(async.iterator(tasks))();
        });
    });
}
```

(referred from [http://baudehlo.com/2014/04/28/node-js-multiple-query-transactions](http://baudehlo.com/2014/04/28/node-js-multiple-query-transactions/)/)

What's wrong with the following function:

### plot.js

```
db.waterfall([
       function(client,cb){
           client.query("INSERT INTO mydb.plotsold" +
                   "(plot_id, agent_id, plot_price, plot_date) VALUES " +
                   "($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING id", soldInfo.PlotId, soldInfo.agentId,
               soldInfo.soldPrice, soldInfo.newDate,cb);
       },
        function(client,results,cb){
            client.query("update mydb.listing " +
                "set status =2 where id = $1 RETURNING id",soldInfo.listingId,cb);

        }
    ],cb);
```

Comment: Is it giving any error?

Comment: Yes getting callback object undefined error

Comment: Can you add the complete error, with stack and line number that's producing the error.